# Converting 2D Numpy array to a list of 1D columns

Tags: python, numpy

What would be the best way of converting a 2D numpy array into a list of 1D columns?

For instance, for an array:

```
array([[ 0,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  6, 11],
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14]])
```

I would like to get:

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])]
```

This works:

```
[a[:, i] for i in range(a.shape[1])]
```

but I was wondering if there is a better solution using pure Numpy functions?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using plain `a.T`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of any reason you would need

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])]
```

Instead of

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Which you can get simply with `a.T`

<sup>If you really need a list, then you can use `list(a.T)`</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
In [20]: list(a.T)
Out[20]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])]
```

Here is another one:

```
In [40]: [*map(np.ravel, np.hsplit(a, 3))]
Out[40]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the list function:

```
list(a.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's *another* way. (I assume x is your original 2d array.)

```
[row for row in x.T]
```

Still uses a Python list generator expression, however.